# Posting form information to iframe keeps opening as in _blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I've been having a problem while posting the server response to the iframe.

What I have in this moment is this:

```
 <form action="//tino.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=232d9e4e7f58021bee21b91bc&amp;id=8a1bcca205" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate display-none" target="hidden-iframe" novalidate>
    <input id='mce-FNAME' name='mce-FNAME'>
    <input id='mce-EMAIL' name='mce-EMAIL'>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
<iframe id='hidden-iframe' name='hidden-iframe' src='//tino.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=232d9e4e7f58021bee21b91bc&amp;id=8a1bcca205' class='display-none'/>
```

The links go to an external website.

The form is getting the data through js, which does come into question as it is working.

The result I expect to achieve is that the response for this form is hidden.

The result I am getting is the result being opened in a new tab (or window) as in target='_blank'.

I do not want to use PHP or another type of server for now, would like an js/html solution.

Is there something I'm doing wrong that I did not see?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are both pages in the same sub-domain (`tino.us11`) and domain (`list-manage.com`)? BTW your iframe needs a closing tag (`<iframe src="sub-domain.domain.com/path/to/page.html"></iframe>`). It will not work as (`<iframe src="sub-domain.domain.com/path/to/page.html"/>`)

Comment: @zer00ne I'm using <iframe /> to close it... I guess it is not that.
And about the domain, i guess they are.. I've copied the one on the frame from the one on the form... But I'll take a look, thanks :)

Comment: Then I guess since you can re-write fundamental rules of tags, then you should be able to re-write rules of cross-orgin as well https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe Copy and pasting is a poor substute for functional coding. Browsers will compensate for minor typos. If one is allowed, results are varied and unwanted behavior is to be expected.